# ZMQ socket is not thread-safe, but can I use zmq_send() and zmq_recv() in different threads?

Tags: multithreading, zeromq

I know `ZMQ` is not thread-safe.

But I want use one thread receive data:`zmq_poll()` wait data come, then use `zmq_recv()` receive data; use another thread send data: `zmq_send()`

I want to know is this a right way to use `ZMQ`?
In fact I have try it. The program core dump when call `zmq_poll()` once, but it only happen once and can't reappear.

Answer (score 2):

The ZMQ Context is the container for all sockets in a single process and is of course thread-safe. The ZMQ Sockets are not thread-safe and they should not be shared between threads. Therefore, the ZMQ Guide recommends creating a dedicated `inproc` socket for each thread. This gives you a very simple and robust approach to connect threads in one process without complicated thread-synchronization mechanisms.

Answer (score 1):

### Well, no one can stop you from trying that idea.

Nevertheless, all the ZeroMQ Gods and Wizards are against your wish.

If you indeed know what you plan to do, so as to handle all the multi-threaded ambiguity, you are free to go and try it on your own.

**If asking** if this "*is a right way to use ZeroMQ?*", do not expect the answer to be violating all the documentation expressed warnings not to do this.

**Anyway,** enjoy the great tools, like the ZeroMQ is, for designing smart, scaleable, low-latency, high-performance distributed heterogeneous systems.

Answer (score 0):

My personal experience with this is that it's safer to use a queue for sharing messages between threads instead of zmq socket. I have tried to use inproc zmq threads PUB/ SUB within a multi-threaded application and it works perfectly on my MACOS `Darwin Kernel Version 20.6.0 x86_64`, but when moving it to Centos 7 `x86_64 GNU/Linux` then inproc threads are unable to receive any messages without `coredump`.